# Count cells based on color if adjacent cell meets criteria

Tags: excel, vba

This problem is probably very easy for one who is more skilled at VBA than I am. My problem is that I want to count cells containing a specific color, but only if it meets criteria in adjacent cell. I've found out how to do it if I only want to count based on color and this is what it looks like:

```
Function CountCcolor(range_data As Range, criteria As Range) As Long
Dim datax As Range
Dim xcolor As Long

xcolor = criteria.Interior.ColorIndex

For Each datax In range_data
If datax.Interior.ColorIndex = xcolor Then
    CountCcolor = CountCcolor + 1
End If
Next datax
End Function
```

So in my example now I want to count the cells i column B with color green if the adjacent cell i column A equals to Apple.
[Example image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NuV4A.png)

Can you help me? I'm a bit stuck here! Thank you and happy friday everyone!

Answer (score 1):

Just add another condition to your `If` statement

```
If datax.Interior.ColorIndex = xcolor And LCase(datax.Offset(0,-1).Value) = "apple" Then
```

I used `LCase` to get both `Apple` and `apple`...

Of course when you use `Offset` with negative values you have to make sure that you don't apply it to cells that are to close to the end of the sheet (in this case the first column) or you'll get an error.

If you want the cell in the same row as `datax` but column `A`, just use `datax.Row` to get the row number:

```
yoursheet.Cells(datax.Row, 1).Value
```

Where `yoursheet` is the worksbeet you are working on (for example `data_range.Sheet`). You can replace the column index with `"A"` if you like (I prefer working with numbers).

Comment: Great thank you! hmm I realize that I didn't give the total picture of my problem when I started this thread. I actually have multiple columns that contain color but I always want to find the adjacent cell in column A. Is there a way to use the offset function and always use column A instead of counting? I tried with above code that you supplied me and put "A" instead of -1 but that doesn't seem to work :(

Answer (score 0):

Here are few more ways to get the cell on the same row and first column:

```
datax(, 2 - datax.Column)         ' no auto-complete
datax.Offset(, 1 - datax.Column)  ' auto-complete
datax.EntireRow.Cells(1)          ' no auto-complete 
datax.EntireRow.Resize(, 1)       ' auto-complete
```

Comment: The first and second would offset to the right so it should be the negative input. However I think to get to a fixed column offset in any form is confusing. In my opinion the last to options would be preferable although the resize solution seems kind of overkill.

Comment: thanks @arcadeprecinct. I posted it too early in the morning without thinking it trough. I usually use .Offset and .Resize when I want the auto-complete after them.